# Java open file error: can't find the specified path

Tags: java, file, path, fileinputstream

I try to open a .txt file (agenda.txt) from the src/resources folder, read objects from it and add them to an ArrayList, but I get this error: "The system can not find the specified path.". This is the code I use:

```
    public void open(File f) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object o;
        try {
            while ((o = ois.readObject()) != null) {
                model.adauga((Abonat) o);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    this,
                    ex.getMessage(),
                    "Clasa...!",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                this,
                ex.getMessage(),
                "Eroare deschidere fisier!",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    } finally {
        try {
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CarteDeTelefonGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


}
```

And in the class constructor:

```
    private String path ="resources/agenda.txt";
    File f=new File(path);
    open(f);
```

What is wrong in the code?

Comment: try resources//agenda.txt

Answer (score 1):

the file should be located outside *src*, something like *baseproject/resources*. Thats because your path is the project base not your sources directory. Or you can change the code to

```
private String path ="src/resources/agenda.txt";
```

Comment: Another problem now...It works fine on my laptop, but if i run the .jar on another computer it doesn't find the agenda.txt file. How can I fix this?

Comment: you have the exactly same directory structure? what exception are you getting? and please add the exception to your question

Comment: Error: src\resources\agenda.txt (The system cannot find the path specified). In the jar is the resources directory that contains the agenda.txt file and the meta inf directory.

Comment: easy answer: obviously the file is not located there! go to the location of the jar, create a directory _src_, then directory _resources_, and paste there your file _agenda.txt_. extended answer: as i told you before the project directory is your project path! so, modify your code for searching the file in 'resources/agenda.txt' and move the file to that location